# Can the frame rate of video be adjusted and draw text including the *new* frame number in a single invocation of ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am trying to adjust the frame rate `-r fps` of a video, and draw text which includes the **new** frame number `-vf drawtext=text='frame %{frame_num} %{pts}'`. Is this possible with a single invocation of `ffmpeg`?

For example, if I try to process the video with -

```
ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -r 25 -vf "drawtext=text='frame %{frame_num} %{pts}':x=10:y=10" output.mp4
```

when I play `output.mp4`, I see the frame rate indicted `Input #0 25 fps` is correct but the text `frame 3000` is drawn at the 100s point which suggests the original frame rate - 30 fps.

Can I modify the above single call to `ffmpeg` to correct the result or do I have to split the task in to two separate invocations of `ffmpeg` such as -

```
ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -r 25 temp.mp4
```

followed by

```
ffmpeg -i temp.mp4 -vf "drawtext=text='frame %{frame_num} %{pts}':x=10:y=10" output.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but by using the fps filter, not the option `-r`.

```
ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -vf "fps=25,drawtext=text='frame %{frame_num} %{pts}':x=10:y=10" output.mp4
```